# BASH How to save the output of rm -vri to a var

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How can I save the output of this command into a var and still remove the files?

```
rm -vri files | wc -l
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable equal to the output from a command in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ touch file1 file2
$ out=$(rm -vri file1 file2 | wc -l)
rm: remove regular empty file ‘file1’? y
rm: remove regular empty file ‘file2’? y
$ echo $out
2
```

As you can see, using the normal `var=$(command)` method works.

This also works when running it from a script. Obviously, you do need to provide the input (e.g. running it from cron won't work).

Comment: Use quotes: `echo "${out}"`, for instance when your output has more than one line.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I know that you know, but Carlos might not. And he might want to use your solution in other situations, like I did once.

Comment: @WalterA yup thats not the case here, i want to run an option in a bash script wich can remove the files and saves the number of how many files have been erased so i can increment that number in another var! But thanks anyway, I was not aware of that option! I'm learning bash at university so yeap, pretty noob yet!